# center subview according to other subview when both have the same superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have contentView and 2 subviews. 
I want to center subviewA according to subviewB

subviewA and subviewB have the same superview.

this is what I'm doing now to center subviewA(activity indicator) above uitableview.

```
self.subViewA.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.tableView.frame)-self.subViewA.bounds.size.width/2,
                                                                 CGRectGetMidY(self.tableView.frame)-self.subViewA.bounds.size.height/2,
                                                                 self.subViewA.bounds.size.width,
                                                                 self.subViewA.bounds.size.height);
```

Is there cleaner/short way ? any method that exist and I'm missing :) ?

I thought maybe there is somthing like : subviewA.frame = centerInOtherFrame(self.subviewB.frame)

Comment: Constraints ? If you get frame, etc, you can do it by code.

Comment: Will there be some dynamic behaviour of your views? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: I update the question. I'm not using auto layout.
only by code inside layoutSubViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be simplified by

```
self.subViewA.center = self.tableView.center;
```

Comment: TableView's center is in co-ordinates of its parent view. And SubViewA's center should be in TableView's co-ordinates. So this won't work without appropriate co-ordinate translation.

Comment: @Taha "subviewA and subviewB have the same superview."

Comment: yes that is true. But imagine following: tableView frame=>(0,600,300,300). So tableView.center is (150,300). Also assume subView's size=>(100,100). Now if you set subview's center equal to tableview's center, subview's frame will become (100,200,100,100). Which means subview is not centered in tableView rather it is towards the bottom. This was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Taha in your example `tableView.center` is actually `(150, 750)` and `subview.frame` is `(100, 700, 100, 100)` which is centred above `tableView` (assuming they are both in the same container)